# Why is my texture showing up fine in rendered view but not rendering correctly?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

Here is how it appears in "rendered view":
[image: rendered view]

Here it is when rendered:

[image: Rendered]

Comment: Faces are overlapping, probably.

Comment: Could be that you've hidden objects in the viewport or outliner that still appear in the render. Check if there are objects in the outliner with the eye icon greyed out.

Comment: Ah you were both right! I had some hidden objects and didn't consider them when it rendered! Thank you so much!